# Multiple links/files/folders download using Android phones/Apps

Tags: browser, downloading

How to download all links/files/folders from websites/web directories using android phones/apps?

Answer (score 0):

There is an App on Google Play store name: `HTTrack Website Copier`. You can download whole website with this application .You can download only that file which is allowed by the website server for the users only not whole stuff holded by the server.